# Draggable jQuery, convert pixel of top and left position to percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, percentage

I'm using jQuery Draggable for my project, but the thing is I need to convert the position result of draggable content to percentage so it can be responsive with responsive parent div element.

Here's my code:

```
 $(".test").draggable(
       {
       helper: "clone",
       cursor: "move",
       appendTo: ".content-magz",
       revert: "invalid"
       });

    $(".content-magz").droppable(
        {
           drop: function(event, ui)
           {
                containment: ".content-magz",
                x = ui.helper.clone().attr('id', 'value');    // Store cloned div in x
                y=ui.helper.remove();       // Escape from revert the original div
                x.appendTo('.content-magz').removeClass( "test").draggable( {
                revert: "invalid",
                containment: ".content-magz",
                snap: '.content-magz',
                stop: function () {
                var l = ( 100 * parseFloat($(this).position().left / parseFloat($(this).width())) ) + "%" ;
                var t = ( 100 * parseFloat($(this).position().top / parseFloat($(this).height())) ) + "%" ;
                $(this).css("left", l);
                $(this).css("top", t);
           }});
   }
   });
```

I found this code from another so's answer but it didn't worked for me, is there any solution for this.

Thanks,